# How can I achieve a list item with an X button at the end for removing it? (see screenshots)

Tags: qt5, qlistwidget

I'm using a `QListWidget` along with `QListWidgetItem`.

What I want to do is put a small "X" button at the end of the list item for removing it. Just like the one in QtCreator.

[image]

A link to example code is fine. I just need a hint on how to achieve this.

Comment: For starters, you could peek at Creator's own code ;-) Anyhow, it's a matter of creating a suitable [item delegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes).

Comment: @peppe Creator's code is too complicated for my level. I wouldn't know where to start. Can you give advice as to how I can improve this question?

Comment: As I said, I think you need a custom `QItemDelegate` class (possibly a `QStyledItemDelegate` subclass), and override its methods (esp. `paint()` and `editorEvent()`); you can try just calling the base class, then drawing the X in the right spot; then of course handle mouse presses on the X itself. Then install your delegate on your QListView.